# App crash while trying to change Main layout at run-time

Tags: android

Dear users at stackoverflow i have recently added a new contest to my app "(MinePedia)" and the winner receives a free contest winner app plugin "(com.shadycorp)" and i wanted my apps main activity to display an alternate layout.xml at run-time if the user has the contest plugin"(com.shadycorp)" installed and i have used if and else to try and achieve the results i wanted but my app crashes every time i launch it.So can anyone here please help me

here is the MainActivity of (Minepedia)

```
package com.shadycorp.minecraftrecipebook;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
         Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class));
                }
            });

            Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);
            button9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppInf.class));       
                }
            });

            Button button91 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dlc);
            button91.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DLC.class));
                }
            });

            Button button96 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);
            button96.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Instruction.class));              
                }
            });

            // this
            String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

            int icon = R.drawable.launcher;        
            CharSequence tickerText = "MinecraftPedia"; // ticker-text
            long when = System.currentTimeMillis();         
            Context context = getApplicationContext();     
            CharSequence contentTitle = "MinePedia";  
            CharSequence contentText = "This is the quick launch button for MinePedia";      
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
            Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);

            // and this
            final int HELLO_ID = 1;
            mNotificationManager.notify(HELLO_ID, notification);
            boolean installed  =   appInstalledOrNot("com.shadycorp");  
            if(installed)
            {
            //set if action
                setContentView(R.layout.winner_main);
            }
            else
            {
              //set else action
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
        }
        private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri)
        {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            boolean app_installed = false;
            try
            {
                   pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                   app_installed = true;
            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
            {
                   app_installed = false;
            }
            return app_installed ;            
    }               
}
```

And here is the LogCat

```
04-15 12:01:07.529: E/AndroidRuntime(827): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-15 12:01:07.529: E/AndroidRuntime(827): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shadycorp.minecraftrecipebook/com.shadycorp.minecraftrecipebook.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-15 12:01:07.529: E/AndroidRuntime(827):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
```

Comment: What intent may i ask

Comment: Call findViewById() *after* setContentView()

Comment: you add  extends Activity then where you call layout file

Comment: Why have i got down votes on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use default layout
          line in first statement when on create called because you cant add button without layout

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

}

```
                 public void addButton(){

                  Button button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);
                  button9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),                    

                              AppInf.class));  
                        }
                  });

                  Button button91 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dlc);
                  button91.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
                      public void onClick(View v) {

                          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),           

                                    DLC.class));
                                   }
                  });

                  Button button96 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.help);
                  button96.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
                      public void onClick(View v) {
                          startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),                

                        Instruction.class)); 
                    }
                  });
                     }
```

Now call this method wherever you want and dont forget to add button layout definition in both layout..

Comment: i am saying setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); use in on create then do your stuff. you are not using setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) in oncreate method and adding button layout which givings error

Comment: ok that worked.Both of my layouts have the same components so how do i allow (winner_main) to use the buttons ect.. from activity_main

Comment: now run time you can add button in that layout or create separate method .

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are calling your buttons (or any other UI component) from **a layout that doesn't exists yet**.

You need to run your conditional logic and set the layout *before* calling any component on it.

Also keep in mind: Since they are different layouts, they might not contain the same components, so, when you decide which layout you are going to set, call only the components that are present on it, if you try to call a button and it isn't declared in the current layout, and exception will be thrown.

Comment: You should move your conditional logic to set the template (I mean the if-else block) before calling any button/component. If you still have doubts please paste your templates structure to help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You should fetch all the reference_ID  of each view according to contained layout First .

> Set this condition first before you try to find view using ID .

```
boolean installed  =   appInstalledOrNot("com.shadycorp");  
            if(installed)
            {
            //set if action
                setContentView(R.layout.winner_main);
            }
            else
            {
              //set else action
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }
```

It assumable that you have to  maintain one `Boolean` which indicate which `layout` is present form both while you are using  any of View from both `layout`